# How to fix space instead of backspace in git bash

Tags: git-bash

In my git bash, I want to delete some characters by pressing backspace but When i do it. The backspace button will instead space what i type. How to fix this? I'm on windows 10

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me.
Click on the icon in the upper left of the terminal window.  Select Options, then Terminal.  Under Type, pick a different terminal.  Restart the terminal and see if it works.  For me, any of the XTerm worked; while VT220 and VT100 gave me the same backspace issue you mentioned.  Changing these options changes c:\Users\.minttyrc, which can be edited directly too.

Side note: Even though backspace has your cursor moving ahead, it's probably backspacing correctly in the buffer.  So typing `dir<bs><bs><bs>ls<enter>` will look like `dir   ls`, but it should give you the results of `ls`, not an error `dir: cannot access 'ls'`.

Cheers,
Craig

Comment: Thank you, you've saved my life. I'm using git-bash at work, in strictly controlled environment. No alternatives here. The solution (changing to xterm) solved my problem. Moreover, I've realized that also theme and font may be adjusted, which made working with the terminal real pleasure now ;) Only terrible performance reminds me I'm still in Windows.